# What does "to bat in favour of" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> Inspired by the ruling on Delhi, the Madras HC bats in favour of elected regime in Puducherry.

I have checked all entries of the verb "bat" in various dictionaries like Merriam Webster dictionaries, Collins dictionaries, etc. But I'm still not sure what it means in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a cricket metaphor: the Madras HC [High Court] **plays for** elected regime in Puducherry.  That is, the statement means the court is biased in favour of the elected regime.

The normal grammar would be "the elected regime", but as the original is a newpspaper headline, it can omit "the".

Comment: The phrase is also valid in the US, but it refers to baseball rather than cricket.